# How to create email template using python

Tags: python, email, templates, openerp-7

I want to create a mail template in python as I need some dynamic values and send mail using that template. 
How can I create a `mail.template` using Python?

Comment: Use a template engine such as this http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html

Answer (score 0):

I have recently built some automated email systems that create dynamic reports by calling various APIs. Then you can create a cron job for your python script and voila, you have an automated email system.

You'll want to use the smptlib module here, here is a sample of what I used to send mail...

```
import smtplib  
import string

SMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com:587"

To = 'destination@bringo.com'
From = "bonjour_diamond_jim@gmail.com"
Subj = "Schlaang Corp Presents the Billion Dollar Movie"

Body = string.join((
"From: %s" % From,
"To: %s" % To,
"Subject: %s" % Subj,
"",
formatted_text_string,
), "\r\n")

passverd = 'eatingshrimpandwhitewhineeveryday'
s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTPserver)
s.starttls()
s.login(From, passverd)

s.sendmail(From,[To],Body)

s.quit()
```

If I understand correctly you should be able to send the message to a list of emails by 
changing the To variable to a list of emails. good luck!